# Why use removeAllRAnges() at the start of a selection?

Tags: javascript, dom, range, selection, contenteditable

I have this code working, i just want to understand why do i need to use `removeAllRanges` at the start. Did the **sel** had a ranges in it automatically when initialized?

```
function setCaret(boolean_position) {
   var range = document.createRange();
   var sel = window.getSelection();
   range.selectNodeContents($('#board_code')[0]);
   range.collapse(boolean_position);
   sel.removeAllRanges();
   sel.addRange(range);//setting the caret position
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the selection retrieved from `window.getSelection()` isn't an empty instance like the range created by `document.createRange()`. Notice the difference in these methods names - one creates new instance and second gets the instance.

The reason is simple - you can have multiple range instances, every containing different positions. But there's only one selection per document.

Therefore, before adding range, usually you have to remove old ranges that are currently selected. Unless, of course, that you want to extend current selection.

**Update:** As Tim correctly pointed out, only Firefox supports multiple selection ranges. This means that only on Firefox you're able to select more than one piece of DOM at a time - e.g. you can select table's column or add more selections using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.

Therefore, only Firefox requires that you execute `removeAllRanges()` before adding next ones. Other browsers will automatically remove old ranges.

Comment: As I'm sure you know, it's possible to have multiple selection ranges but only in Mozilla, and in other browsers calling `addRange(range)` will deselect the previously selected range and select `range`, meaning that `removeAllRanges()` is usually superfluous in those browsers.

Comment: Uh... I focused on general aspect and forgot to mention that :) Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong: it seems recent versions of Chrome do nothing when `addRange()` is called and a range is already selected, which is a change from older versions, so `removeAllRanges()` is necessary.

Comment: @TimDown thank you for your expertise is this range and selection support i read a lot of your answers and tips in my previous problems